# Android Studio Workspace Hides Popups On Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, popup, workspace

I am using a MacBook Air with El Capitan installed and when i use Android Studio 1.4 in a workspace i get popups behind other popups. For example when i Open Module Settings then Add/Remove Module the popup appears behind the "Project Structure" popup, and when i have tried to move the "Project Structure" popup the one behind it moves along making it impossible to see fully, especially when removing since that popup is a lot smaller. Does anyone else get this problem and is there any fix?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. While we wait for somebody to hopefully answer this, you can press enter on windows that you know will show up. Though it's always better to read.